# Venn Diagram of a set not containing the intersection of its subsets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm a physics graduate student studying introductory topology. In the definition of a topology, one requirement is that the intersection of any finite number of its subsets should also be an element of the topology.

I struggle to visualize as a Venn diagram a case where two subsets of a set intersect in such a way that the intersection is ***not*** a subset of the original set. For example the set U = {{a,b},{b,c}}. If I draw a blob with the points a and b inside, and this blob is a subset of, say, O, then how is b not a point in O? Isn't the whole blob part of O (as in 'inside' O)?

This probably sounds daft but I'm completely new to set theory.

Comment: You're right that it's impossible for an intersection of subsets $A$ and $B$ of a set $U$ to not be a *subset* of $U$, but it can fail to be an *element* of $U$. For example, the intersection of $\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,c\}$ is the singleton $\{b\}$, which is a *subset* of $\{a,b,c\}$, but not an *element* of it.

Comment: This is a good point you're making for me to make the distinction between a subset and an element. Thanks. Still, is there a way to draw this?

Comment: The intersection requirement in the definition of a topology $\tau$ requires that intersections of subsets are elements of $\tau$, not subsets. So the intersection in the Venn diagram of two open sets is required to be an element of $\tau$, but not required to be a subset. For example, $$\tau=\{\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{b,c\},\{b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$$ is a topology in $\{a,b,c\}$. Here, the intersection $\{a,b\}\cap\{b,c\}=\{b\}$ is an element of $\tau$.

Comment: deleted.k.k.k.k.k.k.k.k.k.k

Comment: A topology is a collection of sets. An arbitrary collection of sets need not be closed under intersections. In your example $\{b\}\notin U$.

Comment: Yes, preciselly, it isn't.  My struggle is to vizualize U. I arrived at this problem from trying to visualize the situation where the condition is not satisfied - i.e. the intersection is not included. Visualizing the case when it is included is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical example of a set of open sets whose intersection is not open is $$  U(n) = (-1/n,1+1/n) \subset \mathbb{R}  \\  \mathcal{U} = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U(n)  \text{.}  $$
Each $U(n)$ is open.  The intersection is closed, $\mathcal{U} = [0,1]$, so is not an element of the topology.  This cannot be a finite intersection (or it would be open).

To render this as a Venn diagram, you would have to have an infinite number of regions, so this is not particularly susceptible to representing as a Venn diagram.  (And this is necessary -- again, finite intersections of open sets are still open.)

---

Your example has a universe $\{a,b,c\}$ with the distinguished sets $U = \{\{a,b\},\{b,c\}\}$.  As sets, the Venn diagram is two circles with partial overlap.  One circle represents the set $\{a,b\}$, one circle represents the set $\{b,c\}$, the overlap represents the set $\{b\}$, which is not a distinguished set (that is, it is not one of the sets in the list $U$).

When you write $U$ as you did, the circles represent sets.  We may alternatively think of the entire diagram field as the the universe, divided into three regions, "$a$", "$b$", and "$c$".  Then the two distinguished sets are unions of pairs of regions.  It is frequently easier to draw these as subsequent diagrams on a duplicated rectangle and element boundaries.  As a poor model

```
Universe: |aaa|bbb|ccc|
          |aaa|bbb|ccc|
          |aaa|bbb|ccc|

{a,b}:    |***|***|   |
          |***|***|   |
          |***|***|   |

{b,c}:    |   |***|***|
          |   |***|***|
          |   |***|***|

intersection, {b}:
          |   |***|   |
          |   |***|   |
          |   |***|   |
```

Now certainly, the intersection of two subsets of the universe is a subset of the universe.  But the intersection of two distinguished sets need not be another distinguished set (unless your set of distinguished sets happens to have that property, as a topology would).

Another way to see this is to let the universe by $\{a,b,c,d\}$, the distinguished sets be $\{\{a,b,c\}, \{c,d,a\}\}$.  The intersection of the distinguished sets is $\{a,c\}$, not a distinguished set.  The above diagrams can be adapted to this scenario by splitting one region and relabelling as

```
Universe: |bbb|ccc/|ddd|
          |bbb|cc/a|ddd|
          |bbb|c/aa|ddd|
```

Then, other than adding the diagonal boundary, the subsequent diagrams serve for this universe and set of distinguished subsets.

---

However, none of this may get you to where you are trying to go.  It is probably better to model the object you want as a lattice of subsets
$$
\begin{matrix}
   &   & \{a,b,c\} &  &  \\
   & \diagup &  &  \diagdown  &  \\
\{a,b\} &  &  & & \{b,c\}  \\
   & \diagdown &  &  \diagup  &  \\
   &   &  \varnothing  &  &  \\
\end{matrix}
$$
where an edge is drawn if the lower object is a subset of an upper object, and not all edges are drawn (because this would make the diagrams usually too busy to be useful) since by transitivity any lower object connected by a chain of rising edges to an upper object is contained in that upper object.

This fails to be a topology because the intersection of the two lowest nonempty subsets is not in the collection of open subsets, ${}={}$ is not a distinguished set.

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean. I forgot that the elements of a topology are necesserily (by definition) open. Then b in my example would just lie on the dashed border of the blob?

Comment: Well...  It's not enough to just specify a set of points.  You have to specify which subsets are open in the topology.  In your example, it seems that your set of points is $\{a,b,c\}$ and your topology is $\{ \{a,b\}, \{b,c\}\}$.  Then *to be a topology*, the finite intersection $\{a,b\} \cap \{b,c\} = \{b\}$ must also be an open set.

Comment: No, in my example U is specifically made so that it is *not* a topology (i.e. it does not contain {b}. ) This was my whole point. I am struggling to visualize as a Venn diagram the set U (i.e. something which is not a topology). I would be able to draw a Venn diagram if b was included as it is straightforward.

Comment: Your $U$ as a Venn diagram has two circles, one labelled "$\{a,b\}$" and one labelled "$\{b,c\}$".  The intersection is labelled "$\{b\}$".  The two other regions are labelled "$\{a\}$" and "$\{c\}$".

Comment: If the area of the intersection is part of the individual circles, then it should be included in U because the individual circles are subsets of U. But the point b, should be excluded. This is what confuses me.

Comment: @Eva : The point $b$ is not the subset $\{b\}$.

Comment: How do you make a distinction on a Venn diagram between b and {b}. Can you at all?

Comment: @Eva : I'll try to edit in some more explanation in my answer.  But you're starting to convince me that one of us is not connecting the words in your Question to the idea you are facing.

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the notion of a set as an element in the context of a Venn diagram.

Comment: I just read your edited reply. Wow, very helpful. I hugely appreciate that you took all the time to help me! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

The set is the area of the Venn diamgram.  An element is a point in the area.  As for drawing a Venn diagram of a topology it will be difficult as Venn diagrams were not designed for collections of sets.  At best, use different colors for the areas of different sets.

Comment: What if the element is a set itself? Like in our case.

Comment: @Eva.  Read what I said.  All of it.